# Block domain pointing with virtual host in litespeed

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns, litespeed, dedicated-server

I run my website on dedicated server with
LiteSpeed Web Server and using WHM (WordPress CMS)

My problem is that some other website domain is pointing to my website, If I update or modify its getting updated on other domain too

What I try so far:

- block his IP Server
- DMCA not useful
- changing code and theme

I search and see someone suggest **virtual host**, anyone can help me how to modify  virtual host in lite speed and block access for these sites?

Comment: "My problem is that some other website domain is pointing to my website, If I update or modify its getting updated on other domain too" But why exactly is this a problem? Besides the fact that your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek it's problem because they are duplicate my content and it's bad for SEO.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, create a virtualhost for each domain, example domain-one.com, domain-two.com, so each domain points to its configured one. but you must configure the virtualhost to get all the other domains, so any other unconfigured domain will be presented with the virtualhost "cat-all".

Comment: This video can help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xy_GUip3qAo

Comment: my question is how to create this virtual host ?

Comment: the video I added in the comment above can help you, it shows how to add the virtualhost.